# What is the execution order of Meteor Iron Router hooks?

Tags: meteor

I have some Router code:

```
Router.route('/box', {
    name: 'box',
    action: function(){
        this.layout('appWrapperLoggedInTpl');
        this.render('boxCanvasTpl');
    },
    onAfterAction: function(){
        console.log("onAfterAction executed!");
        renderBoxPage();
    }
});
```

and an onRendered function:

```
Template.boxCanvasTpl.onRendered( function() {
    console.log('onRendered executed!');
});
```

When I run this, the "onAfterAction executed!" appears before the "onRendered executed!" message. I would have thought that the `this.render('boxCanvasTpl');` part of the router code would have executed beforehand, is this not expected?

Answer (score 2):

The execution order is correct but `this.render('boxCanvasTpl');` take some time for the template inserted into the DOM. You may want to move `renderBoxPage();` into onRendered function.